# image file is uploading on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, mysqli

image file is uploading on localhost but not on server!
given below is the error.

Warning: move_uploaded_file(imagesphp/free4all2.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in E:\Inetpub\vhosts\winningsolutions.com.pk\httpdocs\newsserver.php on line 24

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php173F.tmp' to 'imagesphp/free4all2.png' in E:\Inetpub\vhosts\winningsolutions.com.pk\httpdocs\newsserver.php on line 24

Comment: Your server is running Windows?

Comment: yes it is running Winndows.

Comment: What is the operating system of your server?

Comment: Windows is the operating system.

Comment: What version of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `imagesphp` directory is writable by your webserver. Permissions can be set via for example FTP or via an admin panel of your website.

Comment: And the `C:\Windows\Temp\` directory too? Make sure it is both readable and writeable by your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have write permission.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx

Comment: the user do have all type of permissions i.e write, read, modify etc.

Answer (score 0):

Find your upload folder and change its permissions. Next images show the steps:

[image: right clic, properties]

[image: Edit permissions]

[image: Add permission]

[image: Add Everyone (Todos in spanish)]

[image: Accept permission]

[image: Check the missing permissions]

I am costarrican (I speak spanish), that's why I entered the name "Todos" (forth image), but in english you should name it "Everyone". These are special words, you can't name the permission any different.

In the last image, select the created permission ("Todos" or "Everyone"), then mark the unmarked checkboxes in order to have all permissions. Then your upload folder will be ready.

Try ant let us know.